# Electric brewing inside

Tags: wort, boil, electric, bucket-heater

It's starting to get cold out there but I still want to brew.  I started looking into electric brew kettles (i am still new and only using extracts kits).  Most of the stuff I read online is about adding a heatstick to your brew kettle.  I no nothing about welding, so that intimidates me.

I found this [water bucket heater](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BDB4UG) on Amazon that people in the comments talk about using it to supplement their stove top for boiling wort.  Some comments, however, talk about how its hard to clean properly.

Has anyone here used this? and what are your thoughts?  It's currently 50% off, so its only $40, which seems like a great deal if it was to work.

Other then using this, do you have suggesting for brewing inside?

Comment: If you do go this rough be sure to use GFI outlets. Otherwise you risk electrocution. Using a stove is a much better option and works quite well. Just use a lid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're boiling 5 gallons or less on the stove top, then brewing indoors can be done using your regular kitchen setup, assuming you've got an extractor fan in the kitchen to vent all the water vapor. For partial boils, it worked well, but for full boils, it took a over an hour to bring the mash liquor up to temperature, and even longer to bring the full 5 gallons to boil after sparging. The largest ring on the hob was 2.2kW, so YMMV.

I did this for a few months before building a rig based on [www.theelectricbrewery.com](http://www.theelectricbrewery.com).

Comment: On my really quite sad stove in my apartment I can get 5 gallons to boil in 15 to 20 minutes. The key is to keep the lid on which retains a lot of the energy lost to water vapor. Without the lid on it took 45 to an hour to boil. That seemed like an easy fix. I do half batches and full batches in almost the same time as it takes with a propane burner outside.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have a fan on above my stove, so i guess that wont work.  I read the article about the heat source on your site., and it peaked my interest.  I don't have $1500 to spend on a control unit and I dont plan on doing more then 5 gal batches anytime soon, so i think i am going to go a cheaper diy route, like this [one](http://www.instructables.com/id/Electric-brewing-system/?ALLSTEPS).  However your site was awesome and very easy to read for a new brewer and not very electrical person, so i definitely will be buying you a beer.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not my site, but please buy Kal (the guy that runs it) a beer if you find the information useful!

Comment: @mdma Will the water vapor from long term brewing cause damage that a landlord would be irritated with?

Comment: I would guess so if you don't have an extractor.

Comment: @ChrisPlaisier, Leaving the lid on while boiling can trap unwanted dimethyl sulfides in the wort imparting a boiled cabbage taste in your beer.  It also makes it easier to boil over if you are not carefully watching the heat.

Comment: @BoilerBrad, Agreed. Which is why I take the lid off after starting a boil. But to get it up to temp keeping the lid on is very helpful if you don't have a strong heat source. Boil overs are a problem and you just have to check the progress and stir every so often anyway, which hopefully stops that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I bought three of these but after multiple attempts learned they shut off at boiling temperatures and are therefore useless for boiling wort. After discovering this, I thought I would use them to speed up the process of bringing 7 gallons of 170*F wort to boiling, but after a few tests discovered that keeping the lid fully on during this period was faster than the 3 bucket heaters.

I'm going to use them only for a future HERMS setup.

Oddly, when I was doing research on these, about half the posts stated these do not shut off at the boil, while the other half did. Given that only one company produces these, I don't understand the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

I brew using a 36 l (10 gallon) stainless steel kettle on a 3.5 kW stand-alone induction top. Even at 80 % effect, the induction top brings 25 l (6.5 gallon) to the boil in less than 30 minutes.